# Netbeans UI - Shadows on Windows 7

Tags: netbeans, user-interface

I know probably this is not a critical issue but I am curious if anyone could get this problem fixed. I love netbeans and I like how it looks by default on Windows 7, i completely don't like Nimbus, Metal, etc looks, it's great when it's native, but menus, popup menus, code completion suggestion box does not have a shadow, is there a way to keep native windows look of controls but add shadows?